# How to split the query column value into two line inside of anchor tag using coldfusion?

Tags: anchor, cfloop

I've cfquery loop, then I've displayed the one query column value(Text) into anchor tag.

For Example

```
<cfloop query="testQuery">
   <a href="##">#testQuery.Title#</a>
</cfloop>
```

Assume that testQuery.Title variable is return "Defines an explanation/pronunciation of characters (for East Asian typography)"
But I need to break the sentence for Example

"Defines an explanation/pronunciation of
characters (for East Asian typography)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the link into a wrapper and set some width.

```
<cfloop query="testQuery">
  <div style="width:200px !important"><a href="##">#testQuery.Title#</a></div>
</cfloop>
```

Let me know if you have any more problem/it is not working.